# azure-sdk-for-rust: How to get the Content-MD5 for a file?

Tags: azure, rust, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a rust application that uses "azure_storage_datalake" at [https://github.com/ Azure/Azure-Sdk-for-rust](https://github.com/%20Azure/Azure-Sdk-for-rust).  The application can enumerate all of the files, and I can determine the name and size of each file.  What I haven't been able to figure out is how to get the Content-MD5 for each file.  I hope to get the value rather than having to scan each file and determine the MD5 values on the fly. The RESTful API that Azure provides shows the Content-MD5 can be determined,

[Content-MD5 Doc at Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/get-properties?view=rest-storageservices-datalakestoragegen2-2019-12-12#:%7E:text=Content%2DType%3A%20string-,Content%2DMD5%3A%20string,-Date%3A%20string)

I'd appreciate any tips on how to get it using the "azure_storage_datalake" sdk.

Thank you for your time and interest.

Here is the code that I have been developing:

```
let data_lake_client = DataLakeClient::new(
    self.account_name.to_owned(),
    self.storage_credentials.to_owned(),
);

let file_system_client = data_lake_client.file_system_client(container_name);
let directory_client = file_system_client.clone().into_directory_client(".");

let mut page_cnt = 0;
let mut cnt = 0;
let mut response = directory_client
    .list_paths()
    .directory("alm")
    .recursive(true)
    .max_results(NonZeroU32::new(paging_size).unwrap())
    .into_stream()
    .enumerate();

loop {
    let page = response.next().await;

    match page {
        Some((_, p)) => match p {
            Ok(_) => {
                page_cnt += 1;
                let paths = p.unwrap().paths;
                cnt += paths.len();
                paths.iter().for_each(|file| {
                    if !file.is_directory {
                        println!("[{}/{}]: {}, Size: {} bytes, MD5: '{}'",
                                 page_cnt,
                                 cnt,
                                 file.name,
                                 file.content_length as u64,
                                 "tbd".to_string(),  // <<<<< How to get the ContentMD5 value for this file?
                        );
                    }
                });
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("{:#?}", e);
                break;
            }
        },
        None => {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The following is new code that replaces the "if !file.is_directory" block.  It doesn't produce an error, but the properties for any file are always empty.

```
if !file.is_directory {
    let path_name = file.name.clone();
    let file_client = file_system_client.get_file_client(&path_name);
    let file_properties = file_client.get_properties().await;
    println!("{:?}", file_properties.unwrap().properties.unwrap().get("CONTENT-MD5").unwrap());
}
```

Comment: You probably don't actually want the `Content-MD5` value because MD5 is so broken that it doesn't tell you anything useful about the contents of the file.  It's not even "good enough" in any particular use case.  Azure _should_, but unfortunately doesn't, provide something secure like the SHA-256 hash of the file instead.

Comment: I agree with your comments, but it would be too expensive for us to calculate the SHA-256 for existing files. We could, however, attach the SHA-256 as metadata for new ones. This is something to discuss with the team.

Answer (score 0):

Within your `if b.is_directory` branch, you can create a [`FileClient` instance](https://docs.rs/azure_storage_datalake/0.19.0/azure_storage_datalake/clients/struct.FileClient.html#) by [calling `file_system_client.get_file_client`](https://docs.rs/azure_storage_datalake/0.19.0/azure_storage_datalake/clients/struct.FileSystemClient.html#method.get_file_client) method. Then use the [`get_properties` method](https://docs.rs/azure_storage_datalake/0.19.0/azure_storage_datalake/clients/struct.FileClient.html#method.get_properties) to access the [properties](https://docs.rs/azure_storage_datalake/0.19.0/azure_storage_datalake/operations/struct.HeadPathResponse.html) associated with the file. This will contain the MD5 details you are looking for.

```
let file_client = file_system_client.get_file_client(format!("{}/{}", "alm", b.name))
let file_properties = file_client.get_properties().await
println!("file properties: {:?}", file_properties);
println!("MD5: {} ", file_properties.properties.unwrap().get("CONTENT-MD5").unwrap())
```

Note: This solution is not tested.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!  I've adjusted my app accordingly, and things are much closer to working.  Unfortunately, when I get_properties() on a file that has a content-md5 and other metadata, it always returns Some(), but it is empty.  I will continue to debug tomorrow.  I will post the code that I have replaced for the "if !b.is_directory block in another comment.

Comment: I've added the replacement code block to the bottom of the original code, so it is formatted properly.

Comment: @ABitofHelp In your updated code, shouldn’t be the get_file_client relative to the directory?

Comment: Hummm...  The path_name is the entire path from the root directory in the container.  When I look at the dump for each file, it seems to be returning valid data, except for the properties field.

Comment: i.e.
Path: 'alm/blobs/projects/abc/reports/report_20221122T170014Z.pdf', 
HeadPathResponse { 
  common_storage_response_headers: CommonStorageResponseHeaders { 
    request_id: 8de09505-d01f-0049-6771-81d19d000000, 
    client_request_id: None, 
    version: "2022-11-02", 
    date: 2024-03-29 0:42:20.0 +00:00:00, 
    server: "Window/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0" },
  }, 
  etag: "\"0x8DC44ACCE53AECA\"", 
  content_length: Some(4028231), 
  content_type: Some("application/pdf"), 
  last_modified: 2024-03-15 5:00:16.0 +00:00:00, 
  properties: Some(Properties({})), 
  acl: None 
}

Comment: When I remove the root folder from the path to the file and put it into get_file_client(), a 404 error is returned...

Comment: Going to review Azure Storage API's docs again and see if I can discover the issue.

Comment: I wrote a similar app in Go using Azure's SDK and the properties were returned for the file that I am using in the data lake.  So, at least I know that the file is okay.

Comment: For those who are following this saga...  I have determined that the azure_storage_datalake's HeadPathResponse does not include all of the properties that are being returned by Azure.  In my case, content-md5 exists in the headers of Azure's response, but azure_storage_datalake does not add it to the HeadPathResponse.  I need to modify azure_storage_datalake's code to include the md5 header.